# Concatenate Contents of Files from Command Line

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking to create a shell script that reads command line arguments, then concatenates the contents of those files and print it to stdout. This is for text files only.

So far I have created an error check to make sure there is at least one argument, otherwise an error is printed. I have figured out how to take the files in the current directory and concatenate them to stdout.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Usage: concat FILE ...\nDescription: Concatenates 
FILE(s) to standard output separating them with divider -----."
    exit 1
fi

for f in *.txt; do (cat "${f}"; echo "-----"); done
exit 0
```

I need to adjust this code to test that the files exist before concatenating anything, and I need it to read the command-line arguments and only concatenate the specified files. As of right now, this code concatenates anything in the current directory that contains ".txt"

This script needs to be able to handle any number of arguments and the text from the contents are divided by "-----" with no extra blank line inserted.

I am new to shell and am having a bit of trouble with this.

Thanks!

Comment: You want `for f in "$@"; do`... to iterate over the arguments....

Comment: Ok I'll try that, but it needs to be only for .txt files. So how can i error check this so that it will only run for .txt files on the command line?

Comment: A condition inside the loop. Like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165961/how-can-i-programmatically-tell-if-a-filename-matches-a-shell-glob-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you wanted to check if the files exist.  Your glob expansion of *.txt should do this effectively but if you're extra extra paranoid you could add a file test operator:

```
if [ -f $f ];
then
   # file exists do do your stuff as above
else
   echo "whoa, that file $f that existed 4ms ago is no longer  there!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"                     ## This will loop through all the variables.
do
  ## This will check if file with txt extenstion exists or not 
  if [ -f $file ] && [ "$(echo $file|awk -F'.' '{print $NF}')" == "txt" ]
  then
    cat $file >> con.txt             ## This will keep on concatenating.
  fi
done
```

Comment: It also needs to be checked that the file is a .txt file and needs to be printed to stdout, not redirected to another file

Comment: @BradBieselin updated answer with file extension check. You can anytime print the content of file onto the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, hate to be annoying. So turns out it doesn't have to be a .txt file. However it does have to at least exist. If it doesnt exist, an error code 2 must be printed to stderr